# java, how to parse json ajax data as jsonArray?(using @requestparam map, not VO)

Tags: java, arrays, json, ajax, parsing

java, how to parse json ajax data as jsonArray?
(using @requestparam map, not VO)

my js ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST"
        ,url : "/test"
        ,dataType : "json"
        ,data: {
            "a": 123
            , "b": "asdf"
            , "c": "Y"
            , "d": "Y"
            , "test": new Array({"num":1, "use":"Y"},{"num":2, "use":"N"},{"num":3, "use":"Y"})
        }
    }).done(function(data){

    }).fail(function(){

    });
```

i did ajax data with stringify(). but did not parsing.

my java code

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String test(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> param, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(param);
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(param.toString());
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("test");

    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("b"));
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("test"));
    System.out.println(jsonArray.size());

    return "";//helloworld.getName()+" Hello World! "+helloworld.getKind(); 
}
```

and i did,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(param);
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("test");
```

but did not parsing.

System.out.print(jsonObject)

```
{a=123, b=asdf, c=Y, d=Y, test[0][num]=1, test[0][use]=Y, test[1][num]=2, test[1][use]=N, test[2][num]=3, test[2][use]=Y}
```

how can i parse, ajax json "test" array data.
why did not parsing??

Comment: use JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("test"); it will help you.

Comment: um..i used org.json.JSONArray but error.(nested exception is org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["test"] not found)

Answer (score 0):

i solved this question.

ajax option 'traditional:true' and json data, "test": JSON.stringify(new Array(...))

should send json in array object, use option 'traditional:true'.